# How do I change template helper function in Spacebars after template has been rendered?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming, spacebars

Currently I have a section on my **Meteor.js** website that renders tags from a reactive collection in a **Spacebars Template**.

I do something simple like this:

```
//Coffeescript Template Helper
Template.Albums.tags = ->
    tags = []
    _.each Albums.find({}).fetch(), (albumObject, index) ->
        tags = _.union(albumObject.tags, tags)
    return tags;
```

```
<!-- Spacebars Template -->
<template name="tagsTemplate">
    {{#each tags}}
         <li class="interfaceItem">
             <a class="tag" href="{{this}}/">
                 {{this}}
             </a>
         </li>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

This works reactively as it should.

My question is:

> How can I change what the helper is returning and force an update to
>   the template?

I desire to filter the results of the tags based on a search bar.
So, when the user starts typing into a **tagsSearchBar**, I need to change what's displayed in the **tagsTemplate**.

I can do the text search and return the results, but I'm not sure how I go about updating the helper and then forcing the template to reload.

If I try to simply change the *template helper function's* definition, then the template doesn't update to the new definition (I think the template is unaware of the helper function's definition change).

Basically, I am trying to figure out how to do Spacebar reactivity for my own purposes.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: For anyone looking at this question, I also found this [example](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/use-deps-dependency-instead-of-session-if-you-can). It was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to change the helper function and have the template re-render when you do so, one approach would be to store the function in a reactive variable, then in your helper, get the function from the reactive variable and execute it. Unfortunately you can't store functions in the Session, so you'd have to use [`Deps.Dependency`](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency):

```
defaultTagFunction = ->
  tags = []
  _.each Albums.find({}).fetch(), (albumObject, index) ->
      tags = _.union(albumObject.tags, tags)
  return tags

searchTagFunction = ->
  # do something else

tagFunction = ->
tagFunctionDependency = new Deps.Dependency()

Template.Albums.tags = ->
  tagFunctionDependency.depend()
  return tagFunction() # tagFunction.call(this) if you need the data context

setTagFunction = (fn) ->
  tagFunction = fn
  tagFunctionDependency.changed()

setTagFunction(defaultTagFunction)

# later
setTagFunction(searchTagFunction)
```

However, there's probably a more appropriate solution. If the behaviour of the interface when you've typed into the search bar is totally different to when the search bar is empty, you probably want a separate template, and then decide which template to show reactively. If the behaviour is mostly the same, it's probably simpler just to add this logic to the existing helpers, something like:

```
Template.Albums.tags = ->
  searchText = Session.get("tagsSearchBar")
  if searchText is ""
    cursor = Albums.find({})
  else
    cursor = Albums.find({tags: searchText})

  tags = []
  _.each cursor.fetch(), (albumObject, index) ->
      tags = _.union(albumObject.tags, tags)
  return tags
```

Comment: Is there no simple way to force an update on a template, or force a helper to be called? Let's say I pass a string into a helper and want to return true or false. Say at the page /tag1/tag2 the lastTagHelper for tag1 is false and for tag2 it is true. Then, using Iron-Router, I navigate to /tag1/tag2/tag3, now the lastTagHelper for tag2 is false, but the template doesn't know to react to this update. Is there no easy way to do something simple like this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem - is the `lastTagHelper` called from the layout template? In that case you could use `Router.current()` inside that helper to get the current page reactively. You can use a fake `Deps.Dependency` to force an update, but the Meteor way is to access the data using a reactive variable so you don't have to worry about manually forcing updates.

Comment: Ultimately I ended up just using `Deps.Dependency`, this seems to be the easiest way to force the template helpers to become reactive. I believe the Meteor team is eventually going to be adding some features that will make things like this more easy. :)